# Hibernate configuration file

Tags: java, hibernate, configuration, mapping, config

It seems that I have a problem with my configuration file but I really don't find out what it could be.

I used to use hibernate 3.6, I now use hibernate 4.2, there are proly some important changes that I ignore, but the doc seems to not change this part.

Here is my configuration file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/Test</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">*****</property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">10</property>
        <property name="maxActive" value="10" />

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>

        <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

      <!-- Mapping files -->
      <mapping resource="database/config/mapping/test.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

And here is my java source:

```
public class CreateDB {
    public static void main(String argv[]){
        try {
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.configure("database/config/DBCreate.cfg.xml");
            ServiceRegistryBuilder serviceRegistryBuilder = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration
                .getProperties());
            SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration
                .buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistryBuilder.buildServiceRegistry());
        DBConnect.Disconnect(null, sessionFactory.openSession()); // Just logout from a session
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Database unreachable.");
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the return statement:

```
mai 02, 2013 11:41:59 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.1.Final}
mai 02, 2013 11:41:59 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.2.0.Final}
mai 02, 2013 11:41:59 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
mai 02, 2013 11:41:59 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
mai 02, 2013 11:41:59 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: database/config/DBCreate.cfg.xml
mai 02, 2013 11:41:59 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: database/config/DBCreate.cfg.xml
Database unreachable.
```

I really don't get what is wrong, maybe someone will be able to enlight me.
Sorry for possible disturbance and if my post isn't adapted, this is my first one.

Best regards.

Comment: Any luck getting this to work?

Comment: I'm currently at work, I'll tell you later today, I think that will do so, I'll keep you aware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify the port in the `connection.url`.

```
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Test</property>
```

Comment: I just tested it, it did not changed anything.

Comment: @user2342594 Shucks, I'm pretty sure you need to specify the port though, must be something else.  This may be a stupid question but is your database up?

Comment: Yup it is, I obviously tried it before posting here.
I think the problem is that the file is not found, I ignore why.

( cf: INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found ) 

I'm looking for it right now

Comment: Okay, so, it was indeed the file which wasn't loaded. I now come out with a new error:  
"mai 02, 2013 10:58:05 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure
INFO: HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null".    Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I have read an article which says in Hibernate 4 we require to mention the "**hibernate**" keyword in the **property name** tag of the configuration file.

Sample format is -

**Hibernate earlier version**

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration  
        DTD//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
    <hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
       <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/noob</property>

       <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>

       <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect</property>

       <property name="connection.username">root</property>
       <property name="connection.password"></property>

       <!-- DB schema will be updated if needed -->
       <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</property>
       <property name="show_sql">false</property>
       <property name="format_sql">false</property>

   </session-factory>
   </hibernate-configuration>
```

**Hibernate version 4**

```
   <hibernate-configuration xmlns="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/hibernate-
        configuration">

   <session-factory>
       <!-- Database connection settings -->
       <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
       <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/noob</property>
       <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>

       <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>

       <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
       <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">1</property>

       <!-- SQL dialect -->
       <property 
          name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect</property>

        <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache -->
        <property  
    name="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider
        </property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    </session-factory>

   </hibernate-configuration>
```

Observe the "**hibernate**" keyword in the **property name** tag

The exact link is as follows -

[hibernate.cfg.xml with Hibernate 4.0.0](http://hannelita.wordpress.com/2012/03/21/hibernate-cfg-hibernate-4-0-0/)

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

When you change the XML file as per above comments, you must change the DTD definition.